# How to integrate CCAvenue Payment Gateway Source Code in my Android Project

Tags: android, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I know Integration of CCAvenue Payment Gateway with Android Project has been asked several time here, but I want to know slightly different question.

I got CCAvenue Source Code and .apk file in Integration Kit.

I tried to copy and paste into my App directory files, but It doesn't works.

There is no Dependencies or manifest setting in Documentation.
Link:
https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/IntegrationKits-WebMobile.rar

Comment: can you clarify what error you are getting? Is your integration seamless non-seamless. search on stackoverflow for webview integration. sample code for integration in android and iphone https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/Mobile_Integraion_Kit.zip

Comment: Error was "Couldn't find Resource file". and my integration was with Seamless.

Comment: need more error logs. Please paste complete error you are getting ( which resource file is missing? )

Comment: I've Undo it, now it will take time to re-implement all the resources.. well thanks for the help.

Comment: well, thanks. I've successfully fixed it and integrated into my app. Now just tell me where should I use my access_code and merchantID for proper response handle

Comment: @Prince can you send sample code for me

Comment: yeah sure.. give me your email address.. or you can download it online.. just search for it, still if you dont get it.. i will send you through mail.

Comment: just see the link given by @Amod Gokhale